# Bash: how to get lines between patterns only if there is pattern2 between them

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pattern-matching

The situation is next. I got log file where logs separated with minus chars like:

```
Timestamp1
---
Log: 1
Address: http://addr1.com
Payload: <soap:Envelope>
             <soap:Body>
                 <context 1-1>
                 <context 1-2>
                 <context 1-3>
             </soap:Body>
         <soap:Envelope>
---;
Timestamp2
---
Log: 2
Address: http://addr2.com
Payload: <soap:Envelope>
             <soap:Body>
                 <context 2-1>
             </soap:Body>
         <soap:Envelope>
---;
Timestamp3
---
Log: 3
Address: http://addr3.com
Payload: <soap:Envelope>
             <soap:Body>
                 <context 3-1>
                 <context 3-2>
             </soap:Body>
         <soap:Envelope>
---;
...
```

I need to get whole log info where some keyword found e.g. if keyword is "context 2-1" next strings should be printed:

```
---
Log: 2
Address: http://addr2.com
Payload: <soap:Envelope>
             <soap:Body>
                 <context 2-1>
             </soap:Body>
         <soap:Envelope>
---;
```

So how can i do this pattern search with "greedy" cut of delimeters around it?

Comment: Remove `...` and show better sample and also show your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/^---/ {:a;N;/---;/!ba;/context 2-1/p}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^---/` when line starting with `---`
  is found
- `a`: label for to come loop
- `N`: add next line to the pattern space
- `/---;/!`: while `---;` if not found...
- `ba` loops to `a` label
- `/context 2-1/p`: when loop terminates, print all lines previously added to pattern space if `context 2-1` is found

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a guideline: [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
$0=="---" {                   # at the fron marker
    flag=1                    # flag up
    buf=""                    # clear the buf
} 
$0=="---;" { flag=0 }         # at the end marker, flag down
{
    buf=buf $0 (flag?RS:"")   # gather buffer, add RS before the end marker
    if($0 ~ "^Payload2")      # if keyword found
        output=1              # output flag up
} 
flag==0 && output==1 {        # after end marker when putput flag up
    print buf                 # output buf
    output=0                  # output flag down
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk logfile
---
Log2
Address2 ...
Payload2 ...
---;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, i know how to cut text between patterns using sed, but i didn't know how to check another existence of second pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS="Timestamp[0-9]+"  -v k="context 2-1"  '$0~k' file2
```

This uses `Timestamp[0-9]+` as a new-line character. `k` is keyword what you want. If `$0` matches the keyword, then print `$0`.